# java interface which i m initiating but not able to access method please read it and clear it

Tags: java

As we know, servlet's `get` method uses the reference of `HttpServletRequest(interface)` variable request and this request variable is able to access method of it's implemented class.

But now when I have an interface `Sanjeev` which contain a `show()` method, I implement it in a class `xxx`. Now in another class I am creating a reference of the interface like this

```
sanjeev sa =new xxx();
sa.show();
```

It's working, but if I do this

```
sanjeev sa;
sa.show();
```

it's not working whenever in case of `HttpServletRequest(interface)` request work. Why?
Please tell me, I am very confused...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow that's a mess. Can you edit that so it's actually readable, please? At the very least separate out the code snippets from your text and format them properly.

Comment: For starters: Punctuation and proper spelling help a lot. Then you can either put your code in those: `\`inline code goes here\``; or put them on a new line (select your code and press Ctrl+k)...

Comment: Hi. This is very basic knowledge. Have you tried reading one of the many online Java tutorials? The tutorials from Oracle/Sun are actually quite good.

Answer (score 3):

If you do this:

```
sanjeev sa;
sa.show();
```

you'll get an error because `sa` *doesn't refer to anything*. You need to initialise an instance of a class before you can call instance methods, and you're *not doing that*. Something that doesn't exist can't perform an action.

Comment: but httpservletrequest is also not initating it's implemented class in any get-post method then why it's able to access method of implemented class

Comment: @SanDas Your web server will be creating an instance of a class that implements the HttpServletRequest interface. By the time you come to work with it, you *are* using an instantiated object, regardless of whether or not you personally created it.

Answer (score 1):

In java if some variable/object (here sa) is not initialized no memory will be allocated to it.. and when you are calling sa.show() here sa means nothing as its not initialized... basic of java "A variable/object should be initialized before using

Comment: plz tell me why this is possible in case of httpservletrequest interface see it in any get-post method of servlet

Comment: Each time a client requests a page it creates a new object to represent that request. Which is already an instantiated.